# Change timer period while running application STM32F4 [C]

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I want change my timer period while running program

I make different measures requiring different timer periods.
After initialization:

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = period - 1; 
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 8399+1;
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);
```

In main function I set: period = 10000;

Then, I receive new value via UART and try to set another value:

```
arr3[0] = received_str[11];
arr3[1] = received_str[12];
arr3[2] = received_str[13];
arr3[3] = received_str[14];
arr3[4] = received_str[15];
arr3[5] = '\0';
per = atoi(arr3);
period = per;
```

But timer period don't changes. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You need more code?

Comment: Yes, With this code we will not able to help you.

Comment: Ok, but I solve a Problem! I have to do initialization again: `timer_Init();` Very simple =)

Comment: @Fracture simple and glitchy.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem with HAL libraries. People who use them have no clue what is behind it.

What is the timer period?
It is the combination of the PCS (prescaller) and ARR (auto reload register). The period is  calculated as (ARR + 1) * (PSC + 1) / TimerClockFreq.

When you try to change the period when the timer is running you need to make sure that it is done in the safe moment to prevent glitches. The safest moment is then the UG event happens.

You have two ways of achieving it:

1. UG interrupt. In the interrupt routine if the ARR or PSC have changed - you should update the register. Bare in mind that the change may happen in the next cycle if the registers are shadowed.
2. Using the timers DMA burst more. It is more complicated to config - but the hardware take care of the registers update on the selected event. The change is instant and register shadowing does not affect it. More details read RM chapter about the timers DMA burst mode.

If you want to use more advanced hardware features forget about the HAL and program it using the bare registers having the full control.

Comment: Hei P_J, thank your for your comment! You have a right, but there are different states. The Period will be changes between 1s, 100ms and 10ms. So I just need measures with 1s steps while 10s, then a measure stops > period changes (get another period value from serial interface) to 100ms and do it while 10s with 100ms... in this case I have different states. There are no "jumps" from one period to another. Or its still "glitchy"? Thank you!

Comment: STM HAL has a dedicated macro for that, __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD, see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/351568/20285). I agree that you still need to know how to deal with the timer in registry level in order to find your way to that macro.

Answer (score 0):

At run time by updating auto reload register we can change the timer value.
I have done this practically.

TIM5->ARR = Value; //This is for timer5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).